# Create a new Netstorm player with access to the whole tech tree

Tags: netstorm-islands-at-war

I'm trying to introduce a friend to Netstorm, but it's a bit difficult to set up a multiplayer game because new players only have access to one or two buildings. We can't set up a fair match without giving him access to the full tech tree.

Is there a way to cheat when creating a new player, so that he starts with either the full tech tree or a tech tree cloned from an existing player?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the "package" subdirectory of your netstorm install, there is a file called "TMaker.exe".

Run it. It will ask you for the name of a player.

Once you start Netstorm and choose a multiplayer game, you should have the full tech tree.